# Django what is "objects" inside a Manager

Tags: django, object, django-managers

Normally I'd access the queryset via `SomeModel.objects()`.

I notice that inside the model, the `objects` is defined to be some Manager, like, `objects=SomeManager()`.

So, if I'm defining a method inside a Manager, how would I access `objects`?

As in...

```
class SomeManager(models.Manager):
    def some_method(self):
        ( HOW WOULD I ACCESS OBJECTS HERE? )

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ... blah blah
    objects=SomeManager()
```

If I wanted to filter something, I suppose I could do `SomeModel.objects.filter` inside the manager, but somehow that feels weird. Would it be something like `self.filter` or something?

Comment: Inside `Manager` I'm pretty sure you can do `self.filter`, what's the issue then?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that your manager is bound to the `objects` attribute of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would just use [self.filter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter10.html), where 'self' refers to the Manager itself. The default Manager for the model is `objects`, and it is automatically created if you don't specify a custom manager. Because you a doing a custom manager, you don't use `objects`, because obviously that would use the default one, and not your custom one.

So, from the Docs, an example would be:

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def title_count(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    num_pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = BookManager()
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You don't access the manager from within itself. There is no need since you have access to all of the methods via `self`

`objects` is the manager in this case. Since you normally use the manager to access things like `filter` and `get` you can access them locally on the class using `self.filter` or `self.get`.

If you need to have something like `select_related` applied to every queryset returned by the manager, you can override the `get_queryset` method.